# Trackpad has no click and no wifi hardware installed on Macbook pro

Tags: keyboard, wifi, battery, trackpad

I just replaced the keyboard and battery of MacBook Pro A1278, and tried to test it while the keyboard and the battery is working properly, but now the trackpad wont click and wifi has error "no wifi hardware installed".

Also the bluetooth is fine.

Any idea how should I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: By taking it in for repair....

Comment: @theonlygusti I'm sorry, but I am the one trying to repair it. I am just new on macbook repair, and this is just the 3rd macbook I tried to repair, and trying to learn more.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't put it back together properly. Follow the instructions on ifixit.com, which will also point out the traps. I suspect that you pulled up some connector, or something isn't seated correctly.

Comment: @benwiggy The tracking on the trackpad is working, only the click is gone, I will try to reassemble it later.